# PictureBox Refresh causes layers above to flicker

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I am trying to read data from ports and show that on a dial. the background is a PictureBox containing the image of a circular scale giving readings, and a Lineshape has been used to represent the dial. The PictureBox has been 'sent to back' to allow visibility of the Lineshape. I'm enclosing representative codes:
if i do this:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ang += 2.0 * Math.PI / 180.0;
        lineShape1.X1 = Convert.ToInt32(lineShape1.X2 - r * Math.Sin(ang));
        lineShape1.Y1 = Convert.ToInt32(lineShape1.Y2 - r * Math.Cos(ang));

    }
```

then it leaves a trace on the PictureBox.

But if i use the Refresh function of the PictureBox, then the dial appears to flicker. i have tried with timer intervals of 10, 15, 20, 50 and 100, but the problem persists.

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ang += 2.0 * Math.PI / 180.0;
        lineShape1.X1 = Convert.ToInt32(lineShape1.X2 - r * Math.Sin(ang));
        lineShape1.Y1 = Convert.ToInt32(lineShape1.Y2 - r * Math.Cos(ang));
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
```

For the sake of the actual problem, it is not possible to increase the interval. What can i do to Show a smooth variation of the dial?

Comment: Don't use LineShape.  Instead use e.Graphics.DrawLine() in the picture box' Paint event.  Call pictureBox1.Invalidate() to ask for a repaint.

Comment: I am new to using the pictureBox componet. so coulnt make out much of this reply untill Larry added the code. Thanks to both of you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Hans Passant suggested, you should not be using a LineShape object. This is a example of code that implement his suggestion (quick, untested):

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}

void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    ang += 2.0 * Math.PI / 180.0;
    var X1 = Convert.ToInt32(X2 - r * Math.Sin(ang));
    var Y1 = Convert.ToInt32(Y2 - r * Math.Cos(ang));

    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

    e.Graphics.DrawLine(
        new Pen(Color.Yellow, 1f),
        new Point(X1, Y1), 
        new Point(X2, Y2 ));
}
```

Also, try to set `this.DoubleBuffered = true;` to avoid the flickering problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. the line drawLine draws isn't that smooth, but nevertheless it serves the primary purpose. even at interval of 10 millisecond, there's no noticeable flickering.. :)

Comment: Dang, I forgot this... I updated the code a bit to add antialias

Comment: Glad it helped, enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

GDI+ is known to have this effect, in general. This is why WinForms has generally been replaced with WPF and XAML. I think, IIRC, `PictureBox` is especially prone to this problem. What you need to do is perform all of your "drawing" on the image in the `PictureBox` outsde of the `PictureBox`. Once all of your drawing is complete, update the `PictureBox` with the new image.

However, if you're drawing new images really quickly and subsequently updating the `PictureBox`, you're still likely to get flicker. `PictureBox` was just not designed for this use case. It's designed, more or less, to display a static image (or one that may change occassionally, but not at a high frequency).

Comment: Thi answer is not usefull. It does not help to solve the problem.